# How to load bugsense.js via webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

My webpack dev server works without issue with my existing set of dependencies so far.

Now I want to use `bugsense` in my project. The `bugsense` library is not in the npm repository.

This is how I include it in my package.json

```
   "dependencies": {
     "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
     "bugsense": "bugsense/bugsense.js",   
     ...
```

The package was downloaded from github as expected.

However when I tried to import it in a es6 js script, like so

```
import bugsense from 'bugsense';
```

I got these error message

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'bugsense' in /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/app/scripts/actions
resolve module bugsense in /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/app/scripts/actions
  looking for modules in /Users/antkong/dev/projects/webview/node_modules
    /Users/antkong/dev/projects/webview/node_modules/bugsense doesn't exist (module as directory)
    resolve 'file' bugsense in /Users/antkong/dev/projects/webview/node_modules
      resolve file
        /Users/antkong/dev/projects/webview/node_modules/bugsense doesn't exist
        /Users/antkong/dev/projects/webview/node_modules/bugsense.webpack.js doesn't exist
        /Users/antkong/dev/projects/webview/node_modules/bugsense.web.js doesn't exist
        /Users/antkong/dev/projects/webview/node_modules/bugsense.js doesn't exist
        /Users/antkong/dev/projects/webview/node_modules/bugsense.json doesn't exist
  looking for modules in /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules
    resolve 'file' bugsense in /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules
      resolve file
        /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense is not a file
        /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense.webpack.js doesn't exist
        /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense.web.js doesn't exist
        /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense.js doesn't exist
        /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense.json doesn't exist
    resolve 'file' or 'directory' /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense
      resolve file
        /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense is not a file
        /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense.webpack.js doesn't exist
        /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense.web.js doesn't exist
        /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense.js doesn't exist
        /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense.json doesn't exist
      resolve directory
        directory default file index
          resolve file index in /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense
            /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/index doesn't exist
            /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/index.webpack.js doesn't exist
            /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/index.web.js doesn't exist
            /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/index.js doesn't exist
            /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/index.json doesn't exist
        use ./lib/node/index.js from package.json
          resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./lib/node/index.js in /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense
            resolve file
              /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/lib/node/index.js.webpack.js doesn't exist
              /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/lib/node/index.js doesn't exist
              /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/lib/node/index.js.web.js doesn't exist
              /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/lib/node/index.js.js doesn't exist
              /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/lib/node/index.js.json doesn't exist
            resolve directory
              /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/lib/node/index.js doesn't exist (directory default file)
              /Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/lib/node/index.js/package.json doesn't exist (directory description file)
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense.webpack.js]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense.webpack.js]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense.web.js]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense.web.js]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense.js]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense.js]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense.json]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense.json]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/webview/node_modules/bugsense]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/webview/node_modules/bugsense]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/webview/node_modules/bugsense.webpack.js]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/webview/node_modules/bugsense.web.js]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/webview/node_modules/bugsense.js]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/webview/node_modules/bugsense.json]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/index]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/index.webpack.js]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/index.web.js]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/index.js]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/index.json]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/lib/node/index.js.webpack.js]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/lib/node/index.js]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/lib/node/index.js.web.js]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/lib/node/index.js.js]
[/Users/antkong/dev/projects/web/node_modules/bugsense/lib/node/index.js.json]
 @ ./app/scripts/actions/someActions.js 21:16-35
```

Webpack fails to load the module due to a missing file.

How can I fix it? Can I simply fix it via some webpack config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that bugsense hasn't set the `main` field of their **package.json** correctly. Webpack figures out where to fetch the library based on that.

To get around this, you could define a [resolve.alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) like this:

```
{
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      bugsense: path.join(__dirname, 'bugsense/bugsense.js/lib/amd/bugsense.js')
    }
  }
}
```

You may need to experiment with that path.

You can also consider pointing at the minified version and then setting [module.noParse](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-noparse) so webpack knows to avoid parsing the file. This could lead to some extra performance.